# Can I use then() when the previous block does not return a promise? I just want some async functions to run in a specific order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Suppose I have 2 async functions and I want them to run sequentially in the order. myGET() and then myPOST(). I have created functions and not chained the operations them with .then() blocks directly because for the reusability of that code. Is there more graceful way to run functions with asynchronous code in a sequence?

```
function myGET() {
  var str = null;
  // use fetch to get text for str
  // if there is some error, str will be null
  return str;
}

function myPOST(value) {
  var str = null;
  // use fetch to post the value and get the text for str
  // if there is some error, str will be null
  return str;
}

myGET()
.then( function(value) {
  if(value == null) return;
  var str = myPOST(value);
  console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: no, `.then` is a Promise method - of course, you could return an Object with a `.then` function, but ... that would not work with Promises - unless you wrote it correctly - not worth the effort

Comment: If you want the post to work only after the get returns some value, then this is the easiest method. But if you want them to work parallely, you can use `Promise.All()`

Comment: of course, a simple solution is `async function myGET() {` - then it will return a Promise

Comment: One could return an already resolved Promise. A resolved promise is also thenable like a standard (maybe maybe not resolved) async promise — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Wrt. a resolved Promise above, note that the subsequent then callbacks are still invoked asynchronously. This is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
Promise.resolve(myGET()).then((value) => {
  if (value == null) return;
  const str = myPOST(value);
  console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. But I was looking up on MDN and found that IE does not still support resolve() yet. It also said that IE does not support promises and fetch API. Is there any way ro solve this?

Comment: @noob_coder you could use [`Promise` polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) and [`fetch` polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch).